# how to print to Printronix Printer?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, printing, label

Does someone has already printed to a printronix printer (serie t5000r) using .NET (visual basic or C#) ?

We already have the file (txt) with the code to generate the label until I know the code it's PGL.

What've done was to use file.copy() to send the file to the LPT1 port (we use this method with Zebra printers and it works fine) but the printer print plain text instead of the label with it's format (barcode, titles, etc).

Any idea?

Here is the label code, thank you in advance:

^CONFIG
SFCC;94
END

^CONFIG
LEFT MARGIN;5
END

^PAPER;LENGTH 80
^PAPER;WIDTH 60
^PAPER;PORTRAIT

^CREATE;ds-label
FONT;FACE 92250
ALPHA
AF2;100;DARK;POINT;8;6;45;40
AF4;100;DARK;POINT;13;6;45;40
AF60;100;DARK;POINT;18;6;45;40
AF61;100;POINT;22;6;30;30
STOP

FONT;FACE 93779
ALPHA
POINT;5;6;10;0;*Some data 1:*
POINT;10;6;10;0;*Some data 2:*
POINT;15;6;10;0;*Delivery Address:*
POINT;20;6;10;0;*NSC Name:*
POINT;24;6;10;0;*CODE barcode:*
POINT;34;6;10;0;*CODE number:*
AF63;17;DARK;POINT;37;6;46;23
POINT;39;6;10;0;*PID:*
AF64;26;DARK;POINT;41;6;28;14
POINT;43;6;10;0;*Label Code:*
AF65;8;POINT;44;6;15;0
POINT;46;6;10;0;*Date:*
AF66;10;POINT;47;6;15;0
STOP

BARCODE
C3/9;X1;H10;BF10;17;26;8
STOP
END

^EXECUTE;ds-label
^AF2;*ALVSBORGSH. YYY-XXX*
^AF4;*IMMINGHAM PORT IMPORTS*
^AF60;*THE CITY*
^AF61;*Great Britain*
^BF10;*11111111111111111*
^AF63;*11111111111111111*
^AF64;*AAAAAAY1T1MMA7290B11111111*
^AF65;*0067PXXX*
^AF66;*2008-10-15*
^NORMAL

^CONFIG
RESET
END

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your text get intercepted somewhere on the way and rendered to a page instead of sent directly to the printer port. I found this article - [How to send raw data to a printer by using Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=322091) - that may be of help.

Comment: Yeah you're right (i guess), Actually I'm not really sure why but yesterday it starts to work properly, maybe it was a problem with the printer's config. At any case it works too from Console, I can use copy o print command, I guess I could send the command from .net if the file.copy() doesn't work properly again. Thank you.

Comment: OK, glad it's working again. So now you generate a file with the text you want on the label and then copy it to the the printer with a copy command? Well, as long as it's working it's good enough :)

(If you think my answer is helpful you could accept it or up-vote it)

Comment: Well another comment about this, if you copy direct to LPT1 just be sure that on the printer the SFCC (PGL MENU) is setted correctly (in my case 94)